# I was trying to create a simple restful web services example and thus created two projects

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2fSm.png)   This is Client.jsp which sends those two params as input to the intended path.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/WebAPI/backend/user/service/getFormParams" method="post">
name:<input type="text" name="username"/>
mail:<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="get"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Web.xml has,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>WebAPI</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/backend/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The controller has,

```
package com.api.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import com.api.bo.ApiBO;
import com.api.vo.ApiVO;
@WebServlet("/ApiController")
@Path("user/service")

public class ApiController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



@POST
@Path("/getFormParams")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,MultivaluedMap<String, String>formParams,JSONObject obj) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {

System.out.println("into do post method");
ApiVO apivo=new ApiVO();

String username = null;
String email = null;

Iterator<String> it = formParams.keySet().iterator();       
while(it.hasNext()){
        username=it.next();
        email=it.next();
    }

    apivo.setUserName(username);
    apivo.setEmail(email);

    System.out.println(apivo.getUserName());

    ApiBO apibo=new ApiBO();

    JSONObject TESTAPI=apibo.printDetails(apivo);

    System.out.println(TESTAPI);


    }
}
```

BO has,

```
package com.api.bo;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import com.api.vo.ApiVO;

public class ApiBO {

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject printDetails(ApiVO apivo) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

    obj.put("UserName", apivo.getUserName());
    obj.put("Email", apivo.getEmail());


    return obj;
}

}
```

But when i try to run the jsp on server and input the fields it shows,

Error: http status: 500 
message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey threw exception

Please some one help me with this error.

Comment: What do you mean by two projects? And what you are trying to do is not the way to learn how to program RESTful. Why do you need a servlet?

Comment: I want to pass the data from one project in eclipse to another project so that i can accept values and do further operation on them.

Comment: You haven't answered my question: why do you need the servlet? If I remove the servlet annotations and define a REST resource is it OK for you?

Comment: yaa... please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check whether dependencies added the build path, If not add the dependencies in to Deployment Assembly or just clean and build you project.

just right click on the project

Deployment Assembly

Add

It will open other window, in that choose

Java Build Path Entries

click Next

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet.init() errors mainly occur due to mismatching of versions of the Jar files.

Check your build path, always make sure to have not added any jars which are mismatching from your server libraries

Comment: Can you please suggest me wat all jars should i add.

Comment: For that please show the complete error stack trace

Comment: i have added the image of errors that came while i was trying to execute the code... PFA

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a simple working example so that you just get started. There are different options to deploy a RESTful service on a Servlet 3.0 capable containers. I'll just give you one of them.

1. web.xml

   ```
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/backend/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
   ```

   As you see the `servlet-class` is not specified which will cause the  container to automatically add the corresponding servlet class for the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` servlet name.
2. `ApiController.java`:

   ```
   @Path("user/service")
   public class ApiController {

       @POST
       @Path("/getFormParams")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public void doPost(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {

           String username = formParams.getFirst("username");
           String email = formParams.getFirst("email");

           System.out.println("username: " + username);
           System.out.println("email: " + email);
       }

   }
   ```

The username and email should be displayed on the server console (that is where you started your server).

The JSP page is not changed.

Note: Your `@Produces` annotation will not work as is. So you better read the basics first before going further, and you will find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#GILIK) the baics of RESTful services (for example).

Comment: Thank u.. i will give it a try